# Reaktor - How to use variables and Interpolation

Tags: programming, reaktor

I am making a Reaktor macro.

Inside the macro I would like to set a variable `panelset`.

I would like to use that variable in OSC mappings like so

OSC Receive Primary Block Properties > Connect > OSC RECEIVE > Address Pattern > ["/1/krypt#{panelset}-1/1"]

I come from Ruby programming where you can do something like

```
panelset = 1
print "/1/krypt#{panelset}-1/1"
```

And get the output `/1/krypt1-1/1`. In Ruby you are 'interpolating a variable into a string' in that example.

Please help me use 'variables' and 'interpolation' in Reaktor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reaktor macros are implemented graphically and not programmatically as in via text. You would need to identify some sort of macro block that allows the text transform you are suggesting then route the result to a parameter pin.